# Error/dplyr_error - arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step

Tags: r

I'm not very literate in programming so if you could bear with me and also explain in easy terms I'd appreciate it!

I'm trying to access data from NatureCounts using the following tutorial:
https://birdstudiescanada.github.io/NatureCounts_IntroTutorial/
My request for a specific dataset was approved, and I can't seem to get past the step of simply logging in to my NatureCounts account via R.
I've done the following upon opening R:

```
     install.packages("remotes")
     remotes::install_github("BirdStudiesCanada/naturecounts")
     library(naturecounts)
     library(tidyverse)
-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.3.0       --
v ggplot2 3.3.2     v purrr   0.3.4
v tibble  3.0.4     v dplyr   1.0.2
v tidyr   1.1.2     v stringr 1.4.0
v readr   1.4.0     v forcats 0.5.0
-- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ tidyverse_conflicts() --
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
library(dplyr)
nc_count(username = "my username")
```

I'm then prompted for my NatureCounts password, so I enter it, and I get the following error:

```
     Error: arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step. 
     x Could not create a temporary column for `..1`.
     i `..1` is `collection`.
     Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

So I run rlang::last_error() and it says:

```
     <error/dplyr_error>
arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step. 
x Could not create a temporary column for `..1`.
i `..1` is `collection`.
```

As I'm not literate in code at all, and I've hardly entered any code to begin with and I've been following the NatureCounts tutorial as it instructs, I'm not sure what this error means or what to do about it.
I hope this is enough context, if not please let me know. This may also be a very niche problem.
Thanks for any help.